# How to obtain a readable format of an article?

Tags: publications

It became a real problem for me. I need to read some old articles for my research but these qualities are so bad that I can't even read the text. For example, this article "https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X74901368?via%3Dihub".

Do you have any opinion on my problem?

Comment: Get the Library to obtain the original on an "Interlibrary loan". Or contact the publishers...

Comment: @SolarMike That should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. Either you try to locate a paper copy (or a copy thereof) of the journal issue via your local library and if necessary via the interlibrary loan or you contract the vendor of the digital copy (sciencedirect in your case) and complain about the quality of the digitised paper asking them to upload a better-quality version. I tried this with another publisher (degruyter) and it took a couple of months before they updated the digital copy of the paper on their website.

Comment: How should I order via "interlibrary loan"? I don't know the process. I guess it is faster than ask the vendor.

Comment: You should ask at your library (your institutional library or another local library taking part in the ILL)

Answer (score -1):

As per my comment you can ask your library to get the paper via an "Interlibrary loan" - just go in to the library with the details of the paper - make sure it is all correct and they will contact you when it is available.

Or, as the publishers - shown on the paper, but I don't know how long they can take...

When I last did an interlibrary loan it was 10 to 15 days and it was ready, but it may depend on how old the paper may be,...

Comment: I asked the publisher. For now, I cant access my local library that is a problem. Hope to get an answer from the publisher so soon.

Comment: @maha_ak1990 which publisher : sciencedirect or elsevier?

Comment: it is ScienceDirect.

Comment: @maha_ak1990 you are missing a trick, never mnd...